# UISwipeGesture not working with subview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a `UIView` called sineWave that renders an animated sine wave.  I add sineWave as a subview by doing `[self.view addSubview:self.sineWave];`.  I have another `UIView` called panedView which is the highest/top view/layer.  As panedView is dragged up, sineWave view is revealed.  I add panedView above sineWave view by doing `[self.view insertSubview:panedView aboveSubview:self.sineWave];`.  When I pan up everything works perfectly.  However, since adding the sineWave view I have an issue swiping up.  When I swipe up, I can see that the swipe method gets called, but my view doesn't move up where it should.  However, if I swipe a second time immediately after my first swipe, my view will move to where its programmed to - revealing the sine wave.  Any idea why this would occur?

```
- (IBAction)handleUpSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    NSLog(@"Swipe UP");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    panedView.frame = CGRectOffset(panedView.frame, 0, -1*self.view.bounds.size.height*.80);
} completion:nil];

    [self displaySine];

}

-(void) displaySine
{
    if(sineIsDisplaying == NO)
    {

    self.sineWave = [[OSDrawWave alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1*self.view.bounds.size.width, (.75*self.view.bounds.size.height), 2*self.view.bounds.size.width, .3125*(2*self.view.bounds.size.width))];

    [self.sineWave setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.sineWave animateWave];
    [self.view addSubview:self.sineWave];
    [self.view insertSubview:panedView aboveSubview:self.sineWave];
    sineIsDisplaying = YES;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Pan view catches the swipe actions as a pan action?

Comment: I don't see how that would be an issue.  The NSLog in the swipe method gets executed.  Also, when [self displaySine] is removed the swipe gesture works perfectly.

Comment: when I do `[self.view.superview addSubview:self.sineWave]` I can get the swipe gesture to work fine.  But its results in the pan not working.